# How to best disable DNSSEC before onboarding to CloudFlare?

Tags: cloudflare, dnssec

In order to avoid offline time for for a DK domain when onboarding them to CloudFlare, I have read this regarding disabling DNSSEC: https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/dnssec/

Where is says:

> If you are onboarding an existing domain to Cloudflare, make sure
> DNSSEC is disabled at your registrar (where you purchased your domain
> name). Otherwise, your domain will experience connectivity errors when
> you change your nameservers.

But I am still unsure due to their wording.

The domain registrar is https://punktum.dk (which is also the TLD for DK domains) and they have a DNSSEC section where you can create, import and remove DNSSEC keys.

The DNS is hosted at dandomain.dk and they have a disable-button for DNSSEC at their dashboard along with the DNS zones.

So, in order to avoid downtime, do I first go to Punktum.dk and remove the DNSSEC keys there and then I wait for 1-3 days before doing the nameserver update to CloudFlare?

Or is that I go to Dandomain.dk (DNS hoster) and disable the DNSSEC there and wait 1-3 days before doing the nameserver update to CloudFlare?

Or it is that I need to do both and if so in which order?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

In DNSSEC, the higher-level domain informs whether its subdomain(s) should be signed or not.

If your domain is signed when its parent domain says it should not be signed, that is harmless; but if the parent says the domain should be signed but it isn't, that makes your legitimate domain data look like a forgery.

So start at the top: first go to the registrar, and remove the keys there.

To minimize possible downtime later, you might also want to reduce the TTL values of your NS, SOA, and any other DNS records you expect need to be modified at the changeover - to something like one hour, 15 minutes or even just 5 minutes, if your DNS hoster allows.

Once you can confirm (with [DNSViz](http://dnsviz.net/) or similar) that the DS record specifying the key(s) of your domain has been replaced by a NSEC3 record to indicate a DNSSEC opt-out (and any TTL reduction has taken effect), then *and only then* you can remove the DNSSEC records from your zones (by going to your current DNS hoster and pressing their "disable DNSSEC" button). This should clean up the remaining DNSSEC records from your zones, tidying up the DNS data for easy migration.

After the migration is complete, you can increase the TTL values again, to allow for more efficient caching of your domain's records.

Comment: Thank you very very much :-) I will try this soon :-)